# Fit img in bounding box

Tags: html, css

I have an image that I want to crop to fit within a bounding box, but should scale to fit 100% width of the page. There are values for left, right, top, and bottom to define the bounding box, but they are relative to the actual image dimensions. I'm not sure if these values would work if the image is resized to fit the window so was thinking I'd have to work with percentages. Ideally, the entire image should be loaded and then cropped according to the bounding box dimensions, but the cropped region should scale to fit the window at 100%.

Is this possible to achieve this with css using margins? This is the code that I currently have been playing with but it doesn't scale to the window's full width yet.

```
    <style>
            .crop {
                    width: 200px;
                    height: 150px;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    position: absolute;
                }

            .crop img {
                width: 400px;
                height: 300px;
                margin: -75px 0 0 -100px;
            }
        </style>

        <div class="crop">

            <img class="background" ng-src="{{ background_image }}">

        </div>
```

Example Crop:
[image: Example Crop]

Expected Result that fits 100% width of window:
[image: Expected Result:]

Comment: post your code here, edit the question and add it

Comment: Just updated my question to show the code that I've been playing with, although I'm not sure if this is the correct approach.

Comment: Do you need the entire, massive image to be loaded, even though you're only going to show a small part of it?  Normally, you'd have the image be 100% full width, then crop the top / bottom as appropriate to "fit"

Comment: For displaying purposes, the entire image doesn't need to be loaded, but the user needs to be able to re-crop the original image. The other alternative is to save the cropped image on the server as well as the original image. But was hoping to just save the original image and crop according to bounding dimensions.